# iPhone 3GS Keeps Rebooting

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, reboot

My 3GS keeps having a strange issue, but I think I've found a pattern.

- First let its battery get low enough to where it turns off on its own
- Recharge it enough to come back on
- After coming back on, every 5 minutes the 3GS just reboots randomly

To fix it, the only thing that works is to do a restore from iTunes (which sucks if the backup is kind of old)

It is out of warranty, has anyone had this issue? Would a new battery help? I'm also wondering if jailbreaking it might help to where there is something I can do command line to fix it (I'm proficient with Linux/SSH).

My wife uses this phone, and it's hard to get her to keep it charged. I'm running iOS 5.0.1.

Comment: Sounds like the battery may be getting old.  Consider asking a repair shop if they can recognize this behavior.

Comment: I've long ago sold it to gazelle.com -- thanks for the info though.

Comment: Then consider closing the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with my Girlfriends iPhone 3G, as you say the only way to resolve is to a restore in iTunes.

So are you and your wife running iOS5 or is the 3GS on another version?

Once that is done it is worth upgrading (if you haven't already) and make the iPhone sync with iCloud and store your backup there. This way if it happens again you can easily restore to an up to date version.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I already have iOS 5.0.1, it is just annoying that it happens every time she let's its battery die.  It would be nice if I could jailbreak it and reset something over SSH so I wouldn't have to restore it to fix it.